# Drag/Drop annotation in map kit not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, core-location, mapkitannotation

I am trying to implement drag/drop annotation on map. Initially the pin is dropped at user's current location which i do with `[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];` but when i drag and drop the pin it returns back to the current location after some time.

Here is the code:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.delegate = self;
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    //MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"PinAnnotationView"];

    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"PinAnnotationView"];
        annotationView.draggable = YES;

    }
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    return annotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{

    if(newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateStarting)  {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedFrom = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped from %f, %f", droppedFrom.latitude , droppedFrom.longitude);
       // annotationView.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging;
    }

    else if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
        annotationView.dragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone;
    }
    else if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateCanceling) {
        // custom code when drag canceled...

        // tell the annotation view that the drag is done
        [annotationView setDragState:MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check the answer of Jordan in this give the best solution for pin change [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164141/iphone-ubercab-aka-uber-map-coordinate)